# declare an array of N pointers to functions returning pointers to functions returning pointers to characters

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Ugly interview question: How would you declare an array of N pointers to functions returning pointers to functions returning pointers to characters in c++? Show it with and without typedef.

Let's say the functions take no params.

Is mine correct with typedef?

```
typedef char* (*f1)();
typedef f1 (*f2)();

f2 a[N];
```

Comment: trick question. I wouldn't.

Comment: `std::array<std::function<std::function<char*()>*()>*, N>` :)

Comment: `char *(*(*name_of_array[N])())()`

Comment: `id<id<char*()>*()>*[N]`

Answer (score 1):

`typedef char *(*(*foo[])())();`

But I definitely agree with @Xploit here. Don't ever write this.

Answer (score 0):

Function returning pointer to characters:

```
typedef char * (*fpc)(void);
```

Function returning pointer to function returning pointer to characters:

```
typedef fpc (*fpa)(void);
```

Array of function pointers to functions returning pointer to function return pointer to characters:

```
fpa my_array[N];
```

I'll leave the non-typedef version to the OP.  There should be no reason to banish typedefs.

Comment: didnt you just repeat the question? he is just asking if he is right.